# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not working on a specific aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm using ScriptManager.RegisterStartuupScript in all my .aspx pages in my webproject.
It's working on all pages except on 1 page it isn't.

The following code snippet is from a page on which it's working:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Retour.aspx.cs" Inherits="SXSorOverview.Retour" culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="auto"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Lang"] != null) { 
            if (Request.QueryString["Lang"].Equals("FR"))
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            } else if (Request.QueryString["Lang"].Equals("EN")) {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            }
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The following code snippet is from the page on which it's not working:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="SXSorOverview.Home" culture="auto" uiculture="auto"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Lang"] != null) { 
            if (Request.QueryString["Lang"].Equals("FR"))
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            } else if (Request.QueryString["Lang"].Equals("EN")) {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            }
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setSelected", "javascript:window.alert('test');", true);
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tried all the solutions that I found so far on the internet but they didn't help.
I'm not using updatepanels.
Does anyone have any idea why the javascript isn't being executed on that one page?

Comment: Is the javascript being rendered on the page?

Comment: Yes. If I place a (test)alert in the  $(document).ready-function, the alert is being shown.

Comment: In that case, it's probably an error in the javascript. Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Hi Pablo, I found the issue.
Apparently it's necessary to have a form on your page in order for Scriptmanager.registerstartupscript to work.